# Difficulty retrieving participant display name in participantLeft Event with Jitsi Meet

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm working on integrating Jitsi Meet into my application, and I'm having trouble retrieving the display name of a participant who leaves a room in the participantLeft event.

When a participant leaves the room, I'm trying to access their display name using the event.displayName property within the participantLeft event listener in JavaScript. However, I'm unable to obtain this information.

```
api.addEventListener('participantLeft', function(event) {
    var participantDisplayName = event.displayName;
    CefSharp.PostMessage(participantDisplayName);
    // Additional code...
});
```